# Understanding Shallow Copy Through Code

Tags: c++

```
 class LinkedList {
 public:
      LinkedList();
      ~LinkedList();
      LinkedList& operator= (const LinkedList& other);
      void insert(int val); // adds a node
 private:
      LinkedListNode* head;
 };
```

Using the default assignment operator,

```
 list_one.head = list_two.head;
```

My understanding is that list_one and list_two now share the elements of the structure originally pointed to by list_two.

What happens when the destructors below run, and why does the program crash?

```
 ~list_two();
 ~list_one();
```

Can someone please provide a detailed, *intuitive* explanation? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to show the definition of your destructor

Comment: Somehow, I think "detailed" and "intuitive" for an explanation are opposed.

Comment: I don't think it should crash unless your destructor tries to delete the head member.  If the destructor does that then since both objects point to the same thing when both get destructed then the thing being pointed at gets deleted twice.

Comment: But wouldn't ~list_one() just be effectively deleting a pointer pointing to NULL?

Comment: `list_one.head` (should) never be modified by anything that happens with `list_two.head`, which includes that the *value* of the pointer is simply an address in memory, and that value is not set to `NULL` by deleting an otherwise-unrelated object.

Answer (score 1):

A shallow copy means that you are copying the *location* rather than the *contents* at that location.

So, you have two pointers to the same location.  Your crash occurs when you use the destructor to release (deallocate) the memory at the same location twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
   int *p1 = new int;  // assume p1 is member of list 1, so you allocate memory
   int *p2 = p1;  // assume p2 is a member of list 2 and you did assignment.
   delete p1;    // now destructor for p1 gets called, so must delete memory
   delete p2;    // now destructor for p2 gets called.  
                 // also must delete dynamic memory.  Umm, Trouble here.
}
```

Assuming you wrote a destructor, this in a nutshell is what will be happening if two objects have members that point to the same dynamically allocated memory.

You will be deleting the same address twice (double deletion error), and doing that is undefined behavior.  More likely than not, a crash will occur.

Answer (score 0):

When `list_two` is deleted, the `head` node pointer and any nodes it pointed to are (or should be) deleted.  But these nodes were not copied to `list_one`, rather the `head` pointer value was copied, which means that it pointed to the same list of nodes as those pointed to by `list_one`.  So when `list_one` is deleted, the program tries to delete the previously-valid object at the previously-valid address currently stored in `list_one.head`.

Comment: But the destructor should be able to properly handle the case where the pointer points to NULL right?

Comment: Only if it is coded to handle that.  And the pointer reference in `list_one` will not be set to `NULL` by the destructor for `list_two`, so there will always be a problem for the `head` pointer.